# Remove items from list if it exists

Tags: python, list, function

My code will not delete the items if they exist in the list.

This is the list I am working with: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

Run the function: `remove_items_from_list(my_list, [1,5,6])`

This is the OUTPUT I am expecting: `[2, 3, 4, 7, 8]`

But I am getting: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

```
def remove_items_from_list(ordered_list, items_to_remove):
    if [items_to_remove] in ordered_list :
        ordered_list.remove([items_to_remove])
    return ordered_list
```

**These are my instructions:**
This function takes two arguments: a list, and a list of numbers to remove from the list. This function will then check if those items exist within that list, and if they exist, then they will be removed.

Comment: Is `ordered_list` really ordered?

Comment: Look at your code. You are checking if ``[ [1,5,6] ]`` exists in ``[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`` - this cannot work.

Comment: no it is not really ordered but that is what the argument is to be called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `[items] in list` checks that: a list containing the list of items is an element of the list. That is, you are asking: is `[[1, 2, 3]]` a member of the list? Probably not.

What you want to do is iterate over the element of `items_to_remove` and do what you did

```py
for item in items_to_remove:
    if item in list:
        list.remove(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
def remove_items_from_list(ordered_list, items_to_remove):
    return [i for i in ordered_list if not i in items_to_remove]
```

Comment: your function does not what was asked and does not what it describes in the function name. it does not manipulate a list, it returns a new list.

Answer (score 1):

The answer blue_note provided is correct, but a more idiomatic approach would be to do it with a list comprehension, like so:

```
return [x for x in ordered_list if x not in items_to_remove]
```

Note that this will not remove the items from the original list, but return a new list without the items (as pointed out by Bastian).

EDIT: Arkistarvh Kltzuonstev beat me to it, but I would still argue that `x not in y` is more idiomatic that `not x in y`.

Comment: it is not the same... the question was to remove items from a list, but you return a new list. depending on where it is used it might break code.

Comment: Considering that the OP presented a function that takes a list, removes items from it and returns the same list, I am assuming this is what he actually wants. If it is important that items should be removed from the initial list, the function should not have a return value (for the sake of clarity).

Comment: Your point is still valid, though, so I have clarified my answer.

Comment: please read what he wrote in his instructions, not assume from his not working code ... the instructions clearly says that the items should be removed from the list